# C++ windows ui automation: Can't list all the child windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

**I am trying to list all the "names" child windows specially: Unmute currently muted (button)**

[image]

Here is my code to list all child:

```
void ListDescendants(IUIAutomationElement* pParent, int indent)
{
    if (pParent == NULL)
        return;

    IUIAutomationTreeWalker* pControlWalker = NULL;
    IUIAutomationElement* pNode = NULL;

    g_pAutomation->get_ControlViewWalker(&pControlWalker);
    if (pControlWalker == NULL)
        goto cleanup;

    pControlWalker->GetFirstChildElement(pParent, &pNode);
    if (pNode == NULL)
        goto cleanup;

    while (pNode)
    {
        BSTR desc;
        pNode->get_CurrentName(&desc);
        for (int x = 0; x <= indent; x++)
        {
            std::wcout << L"   ";
        }
        std::wcout << desc << L"\n";
        SysFreeString(desc);
      
        ListDescendants(pNode, indent+1);
        IUIAutomationElement* pNext;
        pControlWalker->GetNextSiblingElement(pNode, &pNext);
        pNode->Release();
        pNode = pNext;
    }

cleanup:
    if (pControlWalker != NULL)
        pControlWalker->Release();

    if (pNode != NULL)
        pNode->Release();

    return;
}
```

**BUT OUTPUT IS:**

```
ContentLeftPanel
  VideoContainerWnd
    Video Content
```

I just want to the name/caption of that umute/mute button.. for that I need list of all child windows...

Comment: Can't test cause I don't have that app, but you can use IUIAutomationElement::FindAll with proper condition. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement-findall Inspect itself uses UIA so can find them if it can. However, note that when you use inspect you may be in a context where the tree is different than when you run your code. The UI tree is a living thing, depending ultimately on what the end-user does.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was having this issue because tree is LIVING THING. I needed to hover over window before listing all elements.